# Big lag in a game node.js and socket.io (real time)

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I have a big problem with socket.io which makes my real-time game unplayable.

I want my node.js server to send data every 20ms to every connected client (each socket)

But I notice that the client does not receive every 20ms, it receives several at a time every 100 - 200ms and more. which makes the game totally unplayable (very big lag)

Locally it works very well.

Can you help me please ?
Here is a piece of code of my function that sends data (server side):

```
function sendData()
{
  playersList.forEach( (player) =>
  {
    let data = [];
    // code which add data to "data" variable

    socketsList[player.id].emit('refreshGame', JSON.stringify(data));
  });

  setTimeout(sendData, 20);
}

sendData();
```

Comment: my experience its more dependent on code complexity and optimization, noOfPlayers and server specifications. So first thing first try making your code light weight like removing redundancies , flushing memory etc.

Comment: It's the same if a remove all code which make data in my function `sendData()` with `emit('refreshGame', '');` and if I remove the code which reloading the canvas on the client-side (just a `socket.on('refreshGame', console.log('new Date().getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

This happens as there are some network bottlenecks. This happens because of:

1. Packets sent are very big.
2. Slow network.

To mitigate, try to [optimize sending packets](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/what-data-to-exchange-in-multiplayer-real-time-games), IE only send data that is needed. For example, if I have a game with moving and non-moving components, only send the non-moving components once even though you might send the moving components multiple times.

The other option would be to diagnose the network, which is outside the scope of this stackoverflow question.

However, although these are the "facts", there are some un-conventional or small adjustments that seem to fix this issue based on my own experience.

1. Get rid of the JSON.stringify on the emit function. [Socket.emit](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/) automatically does this for you.
2. Place the setTimeout at the beginning of the function, rather than the end.

Also, make sure that `socketsList[player.id]` is the player's actual socket. If you use [socketsList.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) at some point, it would mess up the indexes totally making it send the packets to the wrong client.